# AngularJS pass string from controller with angular variables in it to display in ng

Tags: angularjs

Here is a very simple version of what I'm trying to execute (this data is coming from all different controllers and the link is dynamic depending on where you are). So I can't assign the variables to $scope, I have to build the link in the view.

How do I pass `{{scopeData}}` in a string to a view to use in an ng-href or any other ng function, and have Angular pickup that it is a variable.

[Sample Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E3uVfSaPgI0m0cE8OSpC)

Plain Text: `http://www.google.com/?test={{row.test}}&test2={{row.test2}}`

Should be `http://www.google.com/?test=1&test2=2`

Comment: To get the best possible answer you should include as much information as possible. Like, show how the information is given, how much information is given etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Define in HTML

The first way, you can build this variables on your html, something like this:

```
 <td><a ng-href="http://www.google.com/?test={{row.test}}&test2={{row.test2}}">{{url.display}}</a></td>
```

## Using functions

You can create a function as well, for example:

Create a scope funciton that returns your link:

```
$scope.buildLink = function(row){

  return 'http://www.google.com/?test='+row.test+'&test2='+row.test2;

}
```

Then use this function in your html:

```
<td><a ng-href="{{buildLink(row)}}">{{url.display}}</a></td>
```

You can see this in action
http://plnkr.co/edit/AgZ5erbPB177Y3OGYdLq

## Dynamic Way

You can use [$interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) to compile the String with {{ }}. This $interpolate it is used by Angular $compile.
You pass the string, and the arguments that will be replaced, see the code:

```
 $scope.buildLink = function(row){

  var miniScope = {
    row: row
  };

  var result = $interpolate($scope.url.link)(miniScope);

  return result;

}
```

On your html you receive the value of this function:

```
<a ng-href="{{buildLink(row)}}">{{buildLink(row)}}</a>
```

You can see the plunker in action:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CSXsySKNhiDGWHgiithc

I hope it helps

Comment: My content is dynamic, the link isn't always google.com/?test=, sometimes it's msn.com/?test=, someitmes it's google.com/?somethingelse= So this solution won't work.

Comment: You can pass this argument to your function too, in the second way

Comment: @AndrewWilson it was that ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the `{{}}` syntax inside controller, build a service that make your controllers communicate or encode the address inside the html using `ng-href`

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better solution to your actual problem, but you can nevertheless achieve what you want by using the $interpolate service.

Here's a plunkr showing your demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/dhHl0as9RRmemY1dZz2E?p=preview

Key points:

```
$scope.getUrl = function(row) {
  var exp = $interpolate($scope.url.link);
  return exp({row: row});
}
```

This is not efficient though: you should only call $interpolate once (or every time the url changes), and then reuse the computed `exp` function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use events to communicate data.  See documentation for [$scope.$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast), [$scope.$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit), and [$scope.$on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on).

```
app.controller('testing_href', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on("hrefData", function (event, data) {
    //do stuff with data
  });
});

app.controller('otherController', function($scope) {
  $scope.$broadcast("hrefData", data);
});
```

You can use factories to share data.

```
app.factory("href_data", function () {
  var api = {
    _data: null,
    setData: function (data) {
      this.data = _data;
    },
    getData: factory () {
      return this._data;
    }
  };
  return api;
});

app.controller('testing_href', function($scope, hrefData) {
  var data = hrefData.getData();
});

app.controller('otherController', function($scope, hrefData) {
  hrefData.setData(data);
});
```